# Applying locale to <h:inputText> for double value

Tags: jsf, richfaces, locale

How to apply locale to `<h:inputText>` for decimal values in  Seam Application(JSF-richfaces)? If I add an `<f:convertNumber/>` to my `<h:inputText>` the correct decimal delimiter is shown (e.g. 6,28 instead of 6.20). But when I enter the input value & save, following error message is displayed, if `converter="javax.faces.Double"` attribute used in `<h:inputText>`, if not, an exception is thrown.

Scenario: If locale is to set to German(de), try to enter the input value in `en-US` format or vice-versa.

Error Message/Exception:

> Can't set property 'xxx' on class 'xxx' to value '590'.:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException@11e51bd

Also let me know, if any alternate solution is available.

Below is the code snippet :

```
<h:inputText id="iEuroDollar" value="#{tempCurr.currencyRateEuroDollarValue}" rendered="#{tempCurr.editRates}" maxlength="6" converter="javax.faces.Double" converterMessage="#{msg['error.double.field']}" >
    <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" locale="#{rolePoolAction.requestLocale}"/>
    <a4j:support event="onblur" action="#{conversionAction.checkInputValue(tempCurr)}" reRender="iDollarEuro"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: It would be useful to see the page source code where you have <f:convertNumber tag.

Comment: Here is the code snippet :

<h:inputText id="iEuroDollar"                                  value="#{tempCurr.currencyRateEuroDollarValue}"              rendered="#{tempCurr.editRates}"   maxlength="6"  
converter="javax.faces.Double" 
converterMessage="#{msg['error.double.field']}" >
    <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" locale="#{rolePoolAction.requestLocale}"/>
    <a4j:support event="onblur" action="#{conversionAction.checkInputValue(tempCurr)}" reRender="iDollarEuro"/>
 </h:inputText>

Comment: @user3415262 never post code as comment, it is hard to read.

Comment: Have updated the code snippet question